# mysql LIKE within two words in one column

Tags: php, mysql, where-clause, sql-like

I have mysql table with column "name", where is name writen in format First Last (so it's merged). I need to search init (using %LIKE% propably), but I need to find similarities just by first letters in each word. Normally, I would use just LIKE%, but it will search just in first name, not in last name...

Is there some solution please?

Comment: You want to find names where either the first or last name begins with a letter? Or you need to match both names?

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier I think `init` is a typo for `in it`. And full-text search can't search for single characters.

Comment: @Barmar well... I'm using full text indexes on a InnoDB db and most definitely am searching right now with the letter a, and the search is effectively only returning words containing an a... maybe with MyISAM you are right?

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier I thought there was a minimum word length setting, and it's usually 4.

Comment: @Barmar you are right http://www.electrictoolbox.com/mysql-full-text-index-word-length/ I guess I have to thank my isp on that one :)

Answer (score 1):

This will find rows where either first or last name begins with `A`:

```
WHERE name LIKE 'A%' OR name LIKE '% A%'
```

This will find rows where first name begins with `A` and last name begins with `B`:

```
WHERE name like 'A% B%'
```

If you need to do this kind of thing frequently, it would be better to have separate `first_name` and `last_name` fields.

Answer (score 1):

MySQL supports REGEXP, but you can't always depend on spacing patterns to determine where the first name ends and the last name begins.  This would however work with 95% or better.

However, I would recommend writing a script to rebuild your table to split the name into last and first columns.

Comment: Thank you, I'll try REGEXP, but I'm affraid that I'll need to split that table, as you said..